# User, external_user, and profile relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, relational-database

I could use a bit of help getting these ActiveRecord relationships perfect. Here's the three models I have.

- User: users of the web application
- ExternalUser: users of an external application
- Profile: additional information about the User/ExternalUser

Here are the real life relationships:

- Most users are also external_users
- Very few external_users are users
- Profiles exist for external_users that are also users

This is what I'm thinking of now and would like feedback on:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :external_user
end

class ExternalUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :profile
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :external_user
end
```

Alternatively I can "attach" the profile as attributes in the external_users table, but very few rows would be populated with this information. The profile can really belong to either the user or the external_user as well.

Something just doesn't feel right with how it's set up so there must be a better way.